# Rational Functional Tester

Tags: java, testing

I'm new to rational functional tester, i want to ask if it supports testing gwt based sites? and if it does how can i do that? or what should my project looks like to be able to test it?

Comment: What library are you talking about when you say "rational function tester"?  Are you talking about mathematical rational functions?

Comment: @Makoto: I assume the OP is referring to [IBM Rational Functional Tester](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Functional_Tester).

Comment: What did you try? I'd say it should work as functional tester does support HTML based applications?!

Comment: thanks for your answers but i want to test a web that uses GWT to create a dynamic objects and lists ..., so does it supported like we say that RFT supports Dojo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rational Functional tester does not support gwt application directly. it is automation testing tool support only web based application.